# Has anyone in the US gotten Farfetch'd from a 5km egg?

Tags: pokemon-go

I know some Pokemon are region locked (Farfetch'd is exclusive to Asia, Tauros is to N. America, etc.), or at least that's what has been theorized. However, Farfetch'd (and some others) are still on the list of Pokemon that can hatch from 5km eggs. Has anyone in the US hatched one yet?

Comment: Yikes, didn't see that, definitely a dupe. My bad